# RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '' while running the stored procedure from node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here's the code (code for connection establishment not included below since the error is not related to the connection):

```
let sql = require('mssql');
let fs = require('fs');

migrate_sql_dump(sql_file_path) {
    console.log(`Migrating the data as per the .sql file: ${sql_file_path}`);
    let data = fs.readFileSync(sql_file_path, 'utf16le');
    console.log(data);
    return this.connection.request().query(data)
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(`Error executing query: ${err}`);
            throw err;
        });
}
```

Here's the .sql file which I passed to the `migrate_sql_dump` function.

```
DECLARE @uniqueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @uniqueId = NEWID()

EXEC sp_i_Event 
@streamName='SomeStreamName', 
@streamId='S01', 
@aggregateType='StreamAggregateType',
@aggregateOriginId='{"SomeId":"S01","Status":"Completed"}',
@eventType='SomeEventType',
@createdBy='Self',
@correlationId=@uniqueId,
@data='{"SomeId":"S01","Status":"Completed"}'
```

Doing `console.log(data)` from the `migrate_sql_dump` function gives the same stuff mentioned above and it runs absolutely fine from the Microsoft SQL Server Studio, but gives `RequestError` from node.js.

**EDIT:** With the .sql file having a simple `INSERT` query alone and the encoding set to `utf8` in code, this code works fine.

Comment: I suspect the error is in `sp_i_Event `, which we don't have the definition for. On a different note [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: If `sp_i_Event` had any issues, then the exact same set of queries would not have succeeded from the Microsoft SQL Server Studio application. And I wonder what issues would the sp_ prefix cause to this scenario.

Comment: The link covers why the `sp_` prefix is bad/frowned upon pretty well.

Comment: Yes, but how's that related to this issue? Sorry, I didn't get that.

Comment: `EXEC sp_i_Event` it starts with `sp_`. `sp_i_Event` isn't a Microsoft procedure, so hence my point. In regards to the problem you're having, well, my original comment raises that. There is nothing wrong with the SQL you've provided (well, the syntax), so the problem most be the SP itself; which we don't have the definition of.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned after your original comment, if the SP itself would've been buggy, why would it run perfectly when executed from the Microsoft SQL Server Studio?